# Using cacls to set permission on executables

Tags: windows, windows-scripting

How exactly is it possible to restrict read and execute permissions of a file, and leave everything else in tact. So you can't open the file, although you can do things like move it and delete it etc.

Comment: Have you have any luck with this yet?

Answer (score 1):

`cacls` only supports **basic** permissions. To change **extended** permissions from a command-line you will need to use [xcacls.vbs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ad33a24-0616-473c-b103-c35bc2820bda&;DisplayLang=en&displaylang=en) or something similar. I only just found this when I searched MSDN, but it should do what you what. Information on the use of the script can be found in [this documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825751)